# the article can't show the image in the full mode in drupal 7

Tags: media

my article can't show images in the full view but only in the teaser view, even go to the article content type setting, in the full mode, it is fine that I allow to show the image.

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the display on the content type (manage display link) as it ultimately sets the values of the teaser and full node.